# Terraform circular dependency when using OpenAPI spec for API Gateway with an Authorizer

Tags: terraform, aws-api-gateway, openapi

The context:

- I want to create an API Gateway
- I want to specify the different routes using an OpenAPI yaml file
- I want to setup a Cognito user pool authoriser, so that only logged in users can access the API

All this is relatively standard, the problem is: in order to create the authoriser, I need to reference the API Gateway, and in order to create the gateway, I need to reference the authoriser. So, we have a cyclical dependency, and terraform complains and blocks the deployment.

```js
data "template_file" "apig_template" {
  template = file("${var.template_path_file}/${var.template_name}")

  vars = merge(
    var.apig_template_variables,
    {
      arnCognitoAuthorizer = "${aws_api_gateway_authorizer.eva_ui_authorizer.arn}"
    }
  )
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "apig" {
  name           = "${var.project_name}-${var.environment}-${var.apig_name}"
  description    = var.description
  api_key_source = "HEADER"

  body = data.template_file.apig_template.rendered
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_authorizer" "eva_ui_authorizer" {
  name            = "${var.project_name}-${var.environment}-${var.apig_name}-authorizer"
  rest_api_id     = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apig.id
  type            = "COGNITO_USER_POOLS"
  identity_source = "method.request.header.Authorization"
  provider_arns   = [var.cognito_user_pool_arn]
}
```

with an OpenAPI yaml file:

```yaml
openapi: "3.0.1"
info:
  title: "${name}-api-gw"
  version: "0.1.0"
components:
  securitySchemes:
    CognitoAuthorizer:
      type: "apiKey"
      name: "Authorization"
      in: "header"
      x-amazon-apigateway-authtype: "cognito_user_pools"
      x-amazon-apigateway-authorizer:
        type: "cognito_user_pools"
        authorizerUri: ${arnCognitoAuthorizer}
        identitySource: "method.request.header.Authorization"
        authorizerResultTtlInSeconds: 300
paths:
  /read-data:
    post:
      operationId: Get Reference Data
      summary: Get Reference Data
      responses: "200"
      security:
        - CognitoAuthorizer: []
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        payloadFormatVersion: "1.0"
        type: "aws_proxy"
        httpMethod: "POST"
        uri: "arn:aws:apigateway:eu-west-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${arnLambdaReadRefData}/invocations"
        timeoutInMilis: 30000
```

The error, which happens during `terraform init`:

```
│ Error: Cycle: module.api_gateway_slips_website.aws_api_gateway_authorizer.eva_ui_authorizer, module.api_gateway_slips_website.data.template_file.apig_template, module.api_gateway_slips_website.aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apig
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on how I can resolve this problem? Thank you

Comment: Could you post the exact error message?

Comment: sorry @Karl I missed that. The question has now been updated to include the exact error message

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create separate aws_api_gateway_authorizer resource.
Just update OpenAPI yaml with below code. Authorizer will get created and assigned to api method automatically.

```
components:
  securitySchemes:
    geo-chart-authorizer:
      type: apiKey
      name: Authorization
      in: header
      x-amazon-apigateway-authtype: cognito_user_pools
      x-amazon-apigateway-authorizer:
        type: cognito_user_pools
        providerARNs:
          - ${cognito_user_pool_arn}
```

In your method add security attribute with same name above

```
get:
  responses:
    "200":
      description: 200 response
  security:
    - geo-chart-authorizer: []
```

Above code works for me. I had to reference below AWS documentation.
Example is also provided in below aws documentation
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-enable-cognito-user-pool.html